# Tensorflow Lite for variable sized input

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model much like the tensorflow speech command demo except it takes a variable sized 1D array as input. Now I find it difficult to convert this model to TF lite using tflite_convert which requires input_shape for input.

It's said that tf lite requires fixed size input for efficiency and you can resize input during inference as part of your model. However, I think it would involve truncating the input which I don't want. Is there any way to make this work with TF lite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your model using a fixed shape as in `--input_shape=64`, then at inference-time you would do:

```
  interpreter->ResizeInputTensor(interpreter->inputs()[0], {128});
  interpreter->AllocateTensors();
  // ... populate your input tensors with 128 entries ...
  interpreter->Invoke();
  // ... read your output tensor ...
```